# If else problem, when i run the code its not correctly output it

Tags: python, if-statement, printing

Hi I learning python and have question?

If I input Joe, it print found and not found.
If I input mark it print only found,

The other names or whatever I input it's say correctly, not found, yet I wonder why when I input Joe it's also print not found(else function)

```
a, b = 'joe','mark'
name = input("enter a name:")

if name == a:
    print("found")

if name == b:
     print("found")
     
else:
   print("not found")
```

*note I tried to write the code also like this

```
If name == a or b:
   Print("found")
Else:
  Print("not found")
```

Thanks I only few hours learning python

Comment: you should change the 2nd ```if``` to ```elif```

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/q/15112125/4046632

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a few ways:

One, as @Nin17 said, just change the 2nd if to an elif:

```
a, b = 'joe','mark'
name = input("enter a name:")

if name == a:
    print("found")

elif name == b:
     print("found")
     
else:
   print("not found")
```

The second way would be to use the `or` operator, as you tried to do. Remember that both arguments on the sides of the `or` operator should be boolean values:

```
a, b = 'joe','mark'
name = input("enter a name:")

if name == a or name == b:
    print("found")
     
else:
   print("not found")
```

Comment: or you could do ```if name in (a, b):```

Comment: considering op has a few hours of experience of programming i think sticking to basic conditionals is the best option lmao

Comment: meh, `name in {‘mark’, ‘joe’}` is pretty intuitive

Comment: fair but that gets into like lists and stuff so idk

Comment: Thanks guys, so great community,...thanks again, I already build my first calculator...so happy

Answer (score 0):

"Else" refers to the second condition. It is not respected, so the result of the code block "Else" is displayed. Just do it:

```
a, b = 'joe','mark'
name = input("enter a name:")

if name == a:
    print("found")

elif name == b:
    print("found")
 
else:
    print("not found")`
```

Answer (score 0):

**What you wrote:**

The `else` keyword will only try to find a contradiction with the last `if`. Hence, you have here two condition blocks: a group consisitng of the first `if` alone, and a group consisting of the both the second `if` and the `else`.

**What happens:**

Know that Joe, as any other name, will only try his chance once per block. So `Joe` goes True in the first block and prints "found", then False in the second block and prints "not found".

**How to correct it:**

If you want to unite these two condition blocks into one, so that Joe does not try his chance in the second `if`, replace the second `if` by `elif`, which basically means `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b = 'joe', 'mark'
name = input("enter a name:")

if a in name or b in name:
    print("found")

else:
    print("not found")
```

Use operator "in" for this.